# How to stop a SysRq command?

Tags: magic-sysrq

I used SysRq+J (thaw), now I am being flooded with printk messages: emergency thaw on sr0. It will never stop.

I do not wish to wait, until a SysRq command ends while blocking the terminal all the time. Switching tty's does not help.

**How can I abort a SysRq command?**

The solution must only exclude **one thing: rebooting.**

Comment: SysRq+T dumps a list of tasks and then stops. It doesn't have anything to do with sr0. I don't think any of the SysRq commands causes kernel messages to be printed forever. What makes you think that those messages are caused by a SysRq request?

Comment: Sorry, @Gilles, I meant SysRq+J (Thaw). It prints "Emergency Thaw on sr0".

Comment: Relating SuperUser post: https://superuser.com/q/360360/513541