# SysRq output into |less, |more, |tee?

Tags: stdout, stderr, magic-sysrq

If I issue a SysRq command, how do I redirect that output (whether it is stdout or stderr is documented nowhere) to |less, |more or |tee?

Comment: it's neither: it's kernel's printk(). dmesg might have it, perhaps

Comment: @A.B printk goes in an endless loop?

Comment: try this: SysRq h (to print the help). then run `dmesg`.  You should see the help printed in this output. It ends up somewhere in /var/log/ but that depends on your distribution

Comment: The context is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439131/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specifically redirect the output caused by an Alt+SysRq request. It goes to the console.

The output caused by Alt+SysRq is sent to the kernel logs, so if you want to read it after the fact, you can look for it in the output of the `dmesg` command, or wherever your system stores the kernel logs (e.g. /var/log/kern.log`).

If you're able to type a shell command line, then why would you use Alt+SysRq instead of some equivalent shell command anyway? Alt+SysRq is intended for emergency situations where you can't access the computer normally.